# $A=\{e_k : k=1,2,3\ldots\} $ is closed in $\ell1$

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

$A=\{e_k : k=1,2,3\ldots\} $ is closed in $\ell1$

Let $(x_n)\in A$ such that $(x_n)\to x_0$, where $x_0\in \ell1$

WTS : $x_0 \in A$

We have $||x_n-x_0||_1 \to 0$ in $R$

$\rightarrow \sum_{k\geq 1}|x_n^{k}-x_0^k| \to 0$ in $R$

$|x_n^k-x_0^k| \to 0$ $\;\forall k\in N $

for fixed $n\in N$, because $(x_n)\in A\rightarrow x_n^t = 1$ for some $ t\in N$ and $x_n^k =0 $ $\forall k\neq t$

$\Rightarrow x_0^t=1$ and $x_0^k=0$ forall $k\neq t$

so $x_0 \in A$

Is this proof okay?

EDIT : On a second thought, it is easy to see $||e_k - e_j||_1 = 2 >\frac12 \forall k\neq j$

so it can be shown that the only sequences converging in $A$ are eventually constant ones and hence it is closed  (just like a discrete metric space)

Comment: What is $e_k$?............

Comment: @DanielWainfleet $e_k$ is the sequence that has $1$ only at $kth$ position and 0 everywhere else. It is a pretty standard notation

Comment: @DanielWainfleet please read my edit

Comment: It is indeed a standard notation. Just a reminder that on this site, with so many topics on it and such diverse users, you get more response if you don't expect viewers to know. Your proof is OK. Your second proof is better because it's simpler.

Answer (score 1):

A discrete subset of a metric space has no limit points; it is, therefore, a closed subset of that space.  The $e_k$ form a discrete subset of $\ell^1$.